# Using Banachs fixpoint-theorem to show the uniqueness of a solution of a non-linear integral equation

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

Show, that under the conditions

(1) $-\infty<a<b<\infty, f\in C([a,b]\times\mathbb{R}), F\in C([a,b]\times [a,b]\times\mathbb{R})$

(2) $\exists~1>c\geq 0~\forall x\in [a,b]~\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}:~\lvert f(x,u)-f(x,v)\rvert\leq x\lvert u-v\rvert$

(3) $\exists~L\geq 0~\forall x,y\in [a,b]\forall u,v\in\mathbb{R}:~\lvert F(x,y,u)-F(x,y,v)\rvert\leq L\lvert u-v\rvert$

the non-linear integral equation
$$
u(x)+\int_a^xF(x,y,u(y))\, dy=f(x,u(x)),~~~x\in [a,b]
$$
has exactly one solution in $C([a,b])$.

My proof is inspired by the proof in our lecture for nearly the same theorem: There the right side only depended on $x$.

There is one problem at the end of my proof, where I cannot continue.

**Proof**

The idea is to use Banach's fixed-point theorem.

Write
$$
u(x)=T(u)(x):=-\int_a^x F(x,y,u(y))\, dy+f(x,u(x)),~~~~~x\in [a,b].
$$
Because of condition (1) it is $T\colon C([a,b])\to C([a,b])$.

Because of (2) and (3), it is

$$
\lvert T(u)(x)-T(v)(x)\rvert\leq L\int_a^x\lvert u(y)-v(y)\rvert\, dy+c\lvert u(x)-v(x)\rvert.
$$
Then the next idea is to consider the norm
$$
\lVert u\rVert_{\lambda}:=\max_{x\in [a,b]}\left\{e^{-\lambda (x-a)}\lvert u(x)\rvert\right\}
$$
for a $\lambda >0$ that will be specified later. This norm is equivalent to the max-norm.

Then:

$$
\lvert T(u)(x)-T(v)(x)\rvert\leq L\int_a^x e^{\lambda (y-a)}e^{-\lambda (y-a)}\lvert u(y)-v(y)\rvert\, dy+c\lvert u(x)-v(x)\rvert\\\leq L\int_a^x e^{\lambda (y-a)}\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}\, dy+\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}\\=\frac{L}{\lambda}(e^{\lambda(x-a)}-1)\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}+\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}\\\leq\frac{L}{\lambda} e^{\lambda (x-a)}\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}+\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}
$$

Now I have a problem!

In the proof in our lecture the same way gave

$$
\lvert T(u)(x)-T(v)(x)\rvert\leq \frac{L}{\lambda} e^{\lambda(x-a)}\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}
$$
so the next step was to divide by $e^{\lambda (x-a)}$, getting then
$$
\lVert T(u)-T(v)\rVert_{\lambda}\leq \frac{L}{\lambda}\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}.
$$
So choosing $\lambda>L$ gave the desired uniqueness by Banach.

But here I have the additional summand $\lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}$ and I do not see how to continue, in order to get an equivalent inequation $\lVert T(u)-T(v)\rVert_{\lambda}\leq \underbrace{\mbox{constant}}_{<1}\cdot \lVert u-v\rVert_{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in[a,b]$
$$\begin{align*}
e^{-\lambda (x-a)}|T(u)(x)-T(v)(x)|&\le L\,e^{-\lambda (x-a)}\int_a^x e^{\lambda (y-a)}e^{-\lambda (y-a)}|u(y)-v(y)|\, dy\\
&\qquad\qquad +c\,e^{-\lambda (x-a)}| u(x)-v(x)|\\
&\le L\,e^{-\lambda (x-a)}\,\|u-v\|_{\lambda}\int_a^x e^{\lambda (y-a)}\, dy+c\,\|u-v\|_{\lambda}\\
&=\Bigl(\frac{L\,e^{-\lambda (x-a)}}{\lambda}(e^{\lambda(x-a)}-1)\Bigr)\|u-v\|_{\lambda}+c\,\|u-v\|_{\lambda}\\
&\le\Bigl(\frac{L}{\lambda}+c\Bigr)\,\|u-v\|_{\lambda}.
\end{align*}$$
Since $0<c<1$, $\lambda$ can be chosen large enough to have
$$
K=\frac{L}{\lambda}+c<1.
$$
Then
$$
\|Tu-Tv\|_\lambda\le K\,\|u-v\|_{\lambda}
$$
with $0\le K<1$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it impossible to prove by the $\lambda$-norm that I used? I ask because we used that in the lecture and I do not know if we have to find a new norm...

Comment: I do not know. I was able to do it on an interval $[a,a+h]$ for $h$ small enough.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Why do you define another norm? Your argumentation is the same when using the norm that mathfemi defined, isn't it?

Comment: I do not know if it works as you did, Julián Aguirre, because if I choose $\lambda$ large enough, does then $(e^{\lambda (b-a)}-1)\to\infty$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Sorry, I cannot see your last argument saying one can choose $\lambda$ large enough in order to get $\frac{L}{\lambda}(e^{\lambda( b-a)}-1)+c<1$. Could you pls explain that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have rewritten my answer. It should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you very much from my side!